# Matrix item search & line item display format is too long

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How do I control the search/display name of matrix subitems in netsuite?
For example the matrix item `Product1234` will show up as `ParentProduct : Product1234` in the global search bar and on transaction line items?

We dont want to see `PARENT_SKU + COLON + ACTUAL_SKU`? Where can I control this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SuiteAnswer 12046](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12046/).  (NetSuite login required).  According to this article, there is no field or setting that excludes the hierarchical information, so it appears you cannot achieve what you want with regard to the global search bar, but you could use the formula in that article to set up a custom field to show on transaction lines.